# How to read and write data at a very high speed in C++?

Tags: c++, io

I have to read data from a board which generates data at a very high speed. I have to read this data fast, parse it and write to another file. Since read operation is taken at a very high speed, I have to implement two threads in C++. So that one thread reads and the other one writes data to file. Since read and write buffer are same, locking mechanisms could not be used. Implementing using Ring buffer is not a good solution. Any other idea to implement it in C++ which doesn’t reduce read speed?

Comment: read and write buffer are the same while you write to another file??

Comment: What kind of speed are you talking about ? Be careful, the disks are slow, unless you have special hardware like SSDs, RAID, ... And please mention your OS.

Comment: The board generate 10mbps data. My OS is Windows

Comment: Could you please confirm whether you wish to write this data to a file, display it as an image/video, both or something else? Some of your replies are at odds with your original question. These details are vitally important for an efficient, high-performance design.  Giving incomplete, or actually incorrect, infomation in a question can waste the time of the experienced developers here as they try to solve problems that do not exist.

Comment: I want to do both ie write this data to file and display it as image

Answer (score 1):

Map both files in memory. Use big reading and writing buffers with size equal to a multiple of page size. Use asynchronous memory writes in new file. Start both threads, one for reading and second for writing. Establish a communication message between both threads so, when a new file portion is read, communicate its availability to second thread. Meanwhile you read a new portion of file in a second buffer, parse and write thread may work with its buffer. When you finish this parsing and write operations, communicate it to first thread in order to re-use this buffer.

Comment: Is it same as ping pong buffer?

Comment: It depends of parsing speed. If it's fast enough, you can use a pure ping pong buffer. If not, use a second read buffer and switch parsing from one reading buffer to the second one. The whole real process speed is parsing & writing speed. So, try to improve it. Even, you can use multiple parsing threads.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's best to let the OS handle all the optimizations. So, I'd use some sort of mmap tool - either a mmap(2) system call on Linux/Unix, or a MemoryMapOfFile on Win32.

What this does, is instructing the OS to treat the file as a memory location, using a regular Virtual Memory subsystem. This means the system manages buffering in a globally optimal way, and is generally considered somewhat optimal.

This is a good food for thought:
https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/notes.html.

Answer (score 0):

first of all don't use files, handle this in the RAM if you want good performance. second, it would be helpful if you provide more information - what is it exactly you're reading from?

Comment: if you have to display the data you dont write the data to a file... you send it to the display as soon as a frame is completed...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [condition variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to signal the writer that there is a buffer ready for him.  It is also convenient to put the reference to the buffer in a queue, so the writer can handle multiple buffers.
Remark that if the data is coming faster than it can be handled, at some point there will be congestion.